# Help my maniacal wife decorate our Christmas tree

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

My wife is very, let's say, particular when it comes to putting ornaments on our Christmas tree. Let's get her some code to help her in this trying time.

#### Input

Given an input `2 < n < 10` the height of the tree and `0 < k < n` the distinct number of ornaments.

#### Task

Decorate the tree starting with `1` and increment to `k` as we wrap the ornaments around the tree. If we reach `k` and we have more branches to decorate then start back at `1`.

It is okay if there are not the same number of each ornament on the tree, as long as the pattern is satisfied.

The ornaments should appear above each branch `^` except for the top row.

The tree is structured by starting with one branch  then the next level has + 1 branches with a space between each, staggered from the top like:

```
 ^
^ ^
```

For a third row you would add one more branch and stagger them again such that no branch is on the same column (if you think of it like a grid).

```
  ^
 ^ ^
^ ^ ^
```

#### Output

Output your decorated tree.

#### Examples

#### 1.

`n = 3, k = 2`

```
  ^      //Height is 3
 ^ ^
^ ^ ^
```

Now we decorate each branch starting with 1 and increment to k:

```
  ^
 1 2
 ^ ^
1 2 1
^ ^ ^
```

#### 2.

`n = 6, k = 5`

```
     ^    //Non-Decorated
    ^ ^
   ^ ^ ^
  ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^

     ^    //Decorated
    1 2
    ^ ^
   3 4 5
   ^ ^ ^
  1 2 3 4
  ^ ^ ^ ^
 5 1 2 3 4
 ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
5 1 2 3 4 5
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

#### 3.

`n = 5, k = 1`

```
    ^
   ^ ^
  ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^ ^ ^

    ^
   1 1
   ^ ^
  1 1 1
  ^ ^ ^
 1 1 1 1
 ^ ^ ^ ^
1 1 1 1 1
^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins! Have fun and good luck!

Comment: spaces after each line acceptable ?

Comment: @MukulKumar no It should maintain the structure above.

Comment: Can we assume k less than 10? Or else, how to align the numbers?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes assume < 10 good point

Answer (score 46):

## C# <strike>226</strike> 221 Bytes

*Saved 5 Bytes thanks to @Mukul Kumar and @aloisdg*

Golfed:

```
string C(int n,int k){string o="",x;int j=1,i=1,m;for(;i<=n;i++){o+=string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("^ ",i)).PadLeft(n+i)+"\n";m=0;x="";if(i<n){while(m<i+1){if(j>k)j=1;x+=j+++" ";m++;}o+=x.PadLeft(n+i+1)+"\n";}}return o;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public string C(int n, int k, WifeMode wifeMode = WifeMode.Maniacal)
{
  string o = "",x;
  int j = 1,i=1,m;

  for (; i <= n; i++)
  {
    o += string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("^ ", i)).PadLeft(n+i) + "\n";

    m = 0;
    x = "";

    if (i < n)
    {
      while (m < i + 1)
      {
        if (j > k) j = 1;
        x += j++ + " ";
        m++;
      }

      o += x.PadLeft(n + i + 1) + "\n";
    }
  }

  return o;
}
```

Testing:

```
Console.Write(new ChristmasTreeDecorating().C(20, 9));

                   ^ 
                  1 2 
                  ^ ^ 
                 3 4 5 
                 ^ ^ ^ 
                6 7 8 9 
                ^ ^ ^ ^ 
               1 2 3 4 5 
               ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
              6 7 8 9 1 2 
              ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
             3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
             ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
            1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
            ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
           9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
           ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
          9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
          ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
         1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 
         ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
        3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 
        ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
       6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
       ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 
      ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
     6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 
     ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
    3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
    ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
   ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
  9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

*Edit: I had a play casting `int` to `ConsoleColor`... Tis the season :)*

[image]

*MerryChristmas.gif*

[image]

Comment: You can give `i=1` in the int declaration and remove it from your `for` loop...

Comment: You can replace "\r\n" with "\n". It will run fine with core and mono.

Comment: Good to see a `C#` answer getting some love.

Comment: @jacksonecac Glad you enjoyed it. Couldn't resist once the idea came into my head :)

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff Just when I was starting to think I would never succeed at Code Golf using C#... :)

Comment: @tuskiomi Thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <del>29</del> <del>27</del> 24 bytes

Saved three bytes thanks to Adnan!

```
>GN„^ ×NÝNLO<+²%>ðý}\».c

>G                       For N in [1, ..., input[0]]
  N„^ ×                  Push a string of "^ " N times
       NÝ                Push [0, ..., N]
         NLO<            Compute the decoration offset, sum([1, ..., N])-1
             +           Add the offset value to each array cell
              ²%         Modulo input[1]
                >        Add 1 so that it is in range [1, k] instead of [0, k-1]
                 ðý      Join with spaces, now we have a string with the full decoration for the current layer
                   }     End for
                    \    Remove the last decoration
                     »   Join everything with newlines
                      .c Center all and implicitly display
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=PkdO4oCeXiDDl07DnU5MTzwrwrIlPsOww719XMK7LmM&input=Ngo1)

Comment: I think you can replace `NN>*;` by `NLO`.

Comment: Of course! That's funny because I actually used `N*(N+1)/2` intentionally to get the sum of consecutive integers starting from 1, but I completely forgot that 05AB1E had built-ins for that. Thanks!

Comment: Also, do you need the `ï` part now :p?

Comment: I don't think so ^^ .

Answer (score 12):

### JavaScript (ES6), 97 bytes

It seems like your wife *really* is maniacal, so this doesn't include any leading or trailing newline, nor any leading or trailing space. :-)

```js
f=(n,k,x,s=`^
`)=>n--?(p=' '.repeat(n)+s,x?p.replace(/\^/g,_=>x++%k+1)+p:p)+f(n,k,x||k,'^ '+s):''
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,k,x,s=`^
`)=>n--?(p=' '.repeat(n)+s,x?p.replace(/\^/g,_=>x++%k+1)+p:p)+f(n,k,x||k,'^ '+s):''

console.log(f(6, 5))
```

Answer (score 8):

## C++ 214 - 13 - 3 - 1 -1 - 10 = 186 bytes

golfed

```
#define s std::cout<<
int f(int n,int k){int N=++n,K=0,i=0,I;for(;i<n;i++,N--){for(I=N;I--;)s' ';for(I=0;I++<i&&i-1;)s' '<<(K++%k)+1;s'\n';for(I=N;I--;)s' ';for(I=0;I++<i;)s" ^";s'\n';}}
```

Thanks @ cyoce for saving 1 byte.
Thanks @ conor for *chopping* it down to 186!

Ungolfed + copy&compile

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

#define s(a) std::cout<<a;

int main()
{
    int n,N,k,K=0,i,I;
    std::cin>>n>>k;
    N=++n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++,N--)
    {
        for(I=N;I--;)
        
            s(' ')
            
        for(I=0;I<i&&i-1;I++)
        
            s(' '<<(K++%k)+1)
            
        s('\n')
        
        for(I=N;I;I--)
        
            s(' ')
            
        for(I=0;I<i;I++)
        
            s(" ^")
            
        s('\n')
            
    }
    getch();//or any func to pause the console
}
```

Comment: finally < 200...

Comment: Can you remove the space after `#define s(a)`?

Comment: @Cyoce thanks! I did not know about that!!!

Comment: [186 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%23define%20s%20std%3A%3Acout%3C%3C%0Aint%20f%28int%20n%2Cint%20k%29%7Bint%20N%3D%2B%2Bn%2CK%3D0%2Ci%3D0%2CI%3Bfor%28%3Bi%3Cn%3Bi%2B%2B%2CN--%29%7Bfor%28I%3DN%3BI--%3B%29s%27%20%27%3Bfor%28I%3D0%3BI%2B%2B%3Ci%26%26i-1%3B%29s%27%20%27%3C%3C%28K%2B%2B%25k%29%2B1%3Bs%27%5Cn%27%3Bfor%28I%3DN%3BI--%3B%29s%27%20%27%3Bfor%28I%3D0%3BI%2B%2B%3Ci%3B%29s%22%20%5E%22%3Bs%27%5Cn%27%3B%7D%7D) by changing the define to `#define s std::cout<<` and making according adjustments.

Comment: Woaa..thats nice.. never crossed my mind:p

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, 133 bytes

```python
n,k=input()
d=-1
j=' '.join
for i in range(1,n+1):s=' '*(n-i);print(['',s+j(`x%k+1`for x in range(d,d+i))+'\n'][i>1]+s+j('^'*i));d+=i
```

Answer (score 2):

**Clojure, 223 bytes**

My first go at golfing with Clojure:

```
(let[r repeat](defn d[n k](apply str(concat(r(dec n)\ )"^\n"(flatten(for[i(range 2(inc n))m[nil true]](concat(r(- n i)\ )(butlast(interleave(if m(r\^)(rest(iterate #(inc(mod % k))(dec(/(* i(dec i))2)))))(r i\ )))"\n")))))))
```

When called like `(println (str "\n" (d 6 5)))` a newline makes it nicer on REPL:

```
     ^
    1 2
    ^ ^
   3 4 5
   ^ ^ ^
  1 2 3 4
  ^ ^ ^ ^
 5 1 2 3 4
 ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
5 1 2 3 4 5
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

Un-golfed:

```
(defn tree-row [n k index mode]
  (concat
    (repeat (- n index) \ ) ; Left padding
    (butlast ; Removing trailing space
      (interleave
        ; Either printing carets or numbers...
        (if mode
          (repeat \^)
          ; Using "rest" as the iteration starts from a large value
          ; from which the modulo has not been calculated yet.
          (rest (iterate #(inc (mod % k)) (dec (/ (* index (dec index)) 2)))))
        ; ...and interleaved with spaces
        (repeat index \ )))
    "\n"))

(defn decorate [n k]
  (apply str (concat
               (repeat (dec n) \ ) "^\n"
               (flatten (for [index (range 2 (inc n)) mode [nil true]]
                          (tree-row n k index mode))))))
```

I had some issues with lazy sequences and nested lists but I was able to save some characters by not repeating `repeat` ;) and using `\^` characters instead of `"^"` strings. I could also leave out surprisingly many spaces.

Comment: Nice first answer, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby 107 bytes

```
t=->(n,k){d=[*1..k]*n*n;o=0;(1..n).each{|b|s=' '*(n-b);b>1&&(puts(s+d[o,b].join(' '));o+=b);puts s+'^ '*b}}
```

Called like this

```
t.call(5,4)
```

Output:

```
    ^
   1 2
   ^ ^
  3 4 1
  ^ ^ ^
 2 3 4 1
 ^ ^ ^ ^
2 3 4 1 2
^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 170 bytes

```
i=0;d,j,l;t(n,k){char s[20],r[20];d=k-2;l=n;for(;i++<n;){for(j=0;j<l;++j)s[j]=r[j]=32;for(j=n-i;j<l;j+=2){s[j]=94;r[j]=(++d%k)+49;}s[l]=r[l++]=0;if(i-1)puts(r);puts(s);}}
```

Call with:

```
int main()
{
   t(5,4);
}
```

As a bonus, here's a 4-bit binary version:

```
m=0;b(n,k){char*a="000100100011010001010110011110001001";char s[20],r[20];d=k*4-2;l=n;for(;m++<n;){for(j=0;j<l;++j)s[j]=r[j]=32;for(j=n-m;j<l;j+=2){s[j]=94;r[j]=a[++d%(k*4)];}s[l]=r[l++]=0;if(m-1)puts(r);puts(s);}}
```